# Error "'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" when installing Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to install Jupyter Notebook without installing Anaconda on my Windows. I have followed the steps in https://jupyter.org/install but seems not to work. I have tried to close & reopen the command prompt and restart the Windows but didn't work too. What did I miss?

```bash
C:\Users\xxxxxx>pip install notebook
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (6.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=6.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (25.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (21.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.3.4 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (8.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert>=5 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (7.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio>=1.5 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (1.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from notebook) (6.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.8.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclassic>=0.4.7 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from notebook) (0.5.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->notebook) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=300 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook) (305)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-server>=1.8 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook-shim>=0.1.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (0.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (4.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (6.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe>=2.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<3,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient>=0.5.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (0.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.4.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (2.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbformat->notebook) (2.16.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from nbformat->notebook) (4.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=1.1.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.3->notebook) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi-bindings in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: comm>=0.1.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: debugpy>=1.6.5 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (1.6.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=7.23.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (8.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline>=0.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (5.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.37,<3.1.0,>=3.0.30 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (3.0.38)
Requirement already satisfied: stack-data in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (22.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (0.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio>=3.1.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-events>=0.4.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (0.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-server-terminals in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->jupyter-client>=5.3.4->notebook) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->nbconvert>=5->notebook) (2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert>=5->notebook) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from packaging->nbconvert>=5->notebook) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.8 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from anyio>=3.1.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio>=1.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from anyio>=3.1.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.1->argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-json-logger>=2.0.4 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-events>=0.4.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.3 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-events>=0.4.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rfc3339-validator in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-events>=0.4.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: rfc3986-validator>=0.1.1 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-events>=0.4.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook) (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.37,<3.1.0,>=3.0.30->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: executing>=1.2.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asttokens>=2.1.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pure-eval in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: fqdn in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: isoduration in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (20.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonpointer>1.13 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: uri-template in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webcolors>=1.11 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (1.13)
Requirement already satisfied: arrow>=0.15.0 in c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from isoduration->jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook) (1.2.3)

C:\Users\xxxxxx>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: what happens when you run `python -m pip install notebook` and `python -m jupyter notebook`

Comment: @MZ Yeah, `python -m jupyter` works. How to set that as a global command?

Comment: That means you need to set up your environment variables properly. Search how to add python to your path. It may also mean that your `pip` and `python` environments don't align, if directly running `python -m jupyter` doesn't work but does after properly pip installing. (you'll need to restart your cmd line after adding it to path)

Comment: @MZ I know the ways to set up it on environment variables. `pip` and `python` have been set up globally. But what is jupyter path that I can set in my environment variables path?

Comment: Why don't you just create a batch file somewhere on your batch that just does `python -m jupyter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `<your_python_root>\Scripts` to the `PATH` environment variables. (Go to `Environmental Variables > system variable > Path > Edit`).

Then the system knows where to find `jupyter` command.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a virtual environment for jupyter using `venv`:

```
python -m venv jupyter-venv
```

Activate it with:

```
jupyter-venv\Scripts\activate
```

Then install and run:

```
pip install notebook
jupyter notebook
```

It's no simple one-liner, but it is much simpler than installing anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got into a situation where Python was installed *system wide* but Jupyer was installed *locally* only for you.

If so (and maybe I'm wrong), then here's what happened. When we install Python in Windows, it adds usually 3 environment paths, which in system wide installation may look like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Python\Python310
C:\Program Files\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Python\Launcher
```

`jupyter.exe`, when installed globally, would end up in `...\Python310\Scripts` which is already in `PATH` so we expect a shell to see it. But *locally installed packages* may not fall into the predefined search paths. So we need to add an additional one manually.

In this case, it looks like you have to add to `PATH` the following line:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

We can do it either when a shell starts in it's profile, or edit the environment variable for *personal account* (not *system variables*, as far as we add a path to our private directory).

I think the latter option is better because it doesn't depend on a shell you run a `jupyter` in. So I'd press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to run *Windows Settings*, enter `env` in a search bar, choose `Edit variables for account`, and add a path:

[image: add new path to local env]

Answer (score 1):

Add `<Python root>/Scripts` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, if you don't want to edit your environment variables, you can run Jupyter Notebook with the following:

```
> python -m jupyter notebook
```